# Doctrine ManyToOne relation without primary key

Tags: php, sql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have structure of table like this:

[image]

But in symfony2 project `company` table for me is useless. So, I need to make relation like this:

[image]

I making ManyToOne unidirectional relation in `shop` entity, code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="company_id")
 */
protected $currency;
```

but, then I getting entity error:

> The referenced column name 'company_id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'Acme\ShopsBundle\Entity\Currency'.

If I trying to define `company_id` on `currency` entity as Id

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="company_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
protected $companyId;
```

then I getting another entity error on debug:

> The join columns of the association 'currency' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'Acme\ShopsBundle\Entity\Shop', however 'id' are missing

but If then I removing definition of primary key from main `currency` id, then all works, but problem is that removing primary key from `currency.id` isnt good idea so I dont like that way.

There is another solution to map these entities without any errors?

Sorry for my english, its not my native language..

Comment: I guess you should rethink your database structure. If I'm right, in your schema, one shop has one currency and one currency belongs to one shop. It's what you want to achieve ?

Comment: yes, but I cant change database structure

Comment: After 4 year.. the same problem.. Any luck?:)

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys. Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.